# How to store a form data with multiple images upload into a database MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a form where I'd like to insert some values and upload multiple images into a folder and store all data into a database mysql, but, at the moment, my code uploads and save images but not the rest of form data.

Let's see a screen:

[image]

so, you can see that all form fields are empty except images fields

This is my HTML form code:

```
       <head>
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

</head>

<form action="uploadall.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Nome:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Inserisci Nome" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="author">Autore:</label>
      <input type="text" name="author" class="form-control" id="author" placeholder="Inserisci Paese/Nazione" />
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="description">description:</label>
      <textarea id="editordescription" name="description" cols="45" rows="15" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Inserisci Messaggio">
        </textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editordescription' );
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="misure">Misure:</label>
      <input type="text" name="misure" class="form-control" id="misure" placeholder="Inserisci Paese/Nazione" />
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date">Data:</label>
      <input type="website" name="date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Inserisci data" />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="Disattivo" size="20">



    <div>
        <label for='upload'>Add Attachments:</label>
        <input id='upload' name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    </div>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>

</form>
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){






    if(count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0){
        //Loop through each file
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {



          //Get the temp file path
            $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

            //Make sure we have a filepath
            if($tmpFilePath != ""){

                //save the filename
                $shortname = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

                //save the url and the file
                $filePath = "uploads/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

                //Upload the file into the temp dir
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {

                    $files[] = $shortname;
                    //insert into db 
                    //use $shortname for the filename
                    //use $filePath for the relative url to the file

                    // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
 $author = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['author']));
  $description = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']));
    $misure = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['misure']));

 $date = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['date']));
  $status = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['status']));

                    $servername = "xxxxx";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "INSERT INTO exposition (name, author, description, misure, nameimage, pathimage, date, status)
VALUES ('$name', '$author','$description', '$misure', '$shortname', '$filePath', '$date', '$status');";


if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();




                }
              }
        }
    }

    //show success message
    echo "<h1>Uploaded:</h1>";    
    if(is_array($files)){
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($files as $file){
            echo "<li>$file</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: don't use `mysl_*` functions they are depreciated and no longer supportted

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile you mean *"Don't mix different mysql apis"* ;-)

Comment: I recommend PDO though.

Comment: btw; you don't "have" a multi query. You have "one/a" query.

Comment: Also hide your connection variables!!! Cmon

Comment: oh and I hope those aren't actual login credentials. If they are, you better go and change them right now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- did not notice that only saw `mysql_real_escape_string` then my coding mode just went off

Comment: james changing them from the post still does not do u any good, edit history exists, you need to change them completely from your server

Comment: And where's your second query? `multi_query`

Comment: I changed the password of my hosting and mysql account. So, is there some solutions about my problem? :)